# Will an MVC model used as a field in a controller be overwritten on each request?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Have a currious situation where a colleague wrote some code, and now when multiple people access the page she constructed, the site will overwrite User A's model data with User B's model data, if user B comes in and starts a census after User A.

Is it the fault of the model being used as a field in the controller?  She originally had it static, which horrified me, so she changed it to non static field, but something still seems off to me.

```
namespace App.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private Census _census = new Census();

        public ActionResult UploadCensus()
        {
            return View(_census);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UploadCensus()
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Save Census Model to Database
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've never used models this way, because I pass them back and forth from view to view, but wanted to see if anybody had any ideas.

Comment: Yes you get a controller instance per request so any instance fields will be specific to that instance and request. Static fields will remain but be shared across app domain so each request will be writing to /reading from the same shared field. So this would account for the overwriting behaviour you have observed.

Comment: wouldn't you want to keep track of User B's `Census` as unique to User B?

Comment: Yes, they should be unique to each user.

Comment: Why do you even this instance variable in the first place?

Comment: Couldn't tell you.  She said 'I need to pass it around.'  It's not part of my bit of this project, so I don't really care.  I just wanted to affirm my understanding of a static or instance variable and it's lifetime inside of a controller.

Comment: Looks like someone switched from WebForms to MVC without doing any research about the differences. Yes, you'll have to post things back to your controller, because that's how the web works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Per Ben Robinson this is the correct answer.

Yes you get a controller instance per request so any instance fields will be specific to that instance and request. Static fields will remain but be shared across app domain so each request will be writing to /reading from the same shared field. So this would account for the overwriting behaviour you have observed.